# Catching overflow of left shift of constant 1 using compiler warning?

Tags: c, static-analysis, compiler-warnings, bit-shift, integer-overflow

We're writing code inside the Linux kernel so, try as I might, I wasn't able to get PC-Lint/Flexelint working on Linux kernel code. Just too many built-in symbols etc. But that's a side issue.

We have any number of compilers, starting with gcc, but others also. Their warnings options have been getting stronger over time, to where they are pretty strong static analysis tools too.

Here is what I want to catch. Yes, I know it violates some things that are easy to catch in code review, such as "no magic numbers", and "beware of bit shifting", but that's only if you happen to look at that section of code. Anyway, here it is:

```
unsigned long long foo;
unsigned long bar;

[... lots of other code ...]

foo = ~(foo + (1<<bar));
```

Further UPDATED problem description -- even with bar limited to 16, still a problem. Clarifying, the problem is implicit int type of constant that, unplanned, makes the complex expression violate the rule that all calculations be carried out in the same size and signedness.

Problem: '1' is not long long, but, as a small-value constant, defaults to an int. Therefore even if bar's actual value never exceeds, say, 16, still the `(1<<bar)` expression will overflow and ruin the entire calculation.

Possibly correct solution: write 1ULL instead.

Is there a well-known compiler and compiler warning flag that will point out this (revised) problem?

Comment: No matter what size int is, if bar is too big then the shift is undefined (I think. Some kind of bad, anyway). You seem to be asking for the compiler to warn you about a variable second operand to shift on an int. But you say the problem is that '1' is not long: do you want no warning about a variable shift on a long? I don't see why compiler-writers would expect that warning to be useful, and general warnings about variable second operand to << would result in vast numbers of false positives.

Comment: @onebyone: Assuming `int` is 32 bits and `long long` is 64, `~(foo + (1<<bar))` only works for `0<=bar<32`, while `~(foo + (1LL<<bar))` works for `0<=bar<64`.  I assume that OP wants a warning when the former is written instead of the latter.

Comment: Sure, but would he want that warning in cases where foo is an int and bar is logically constrained (but not by type) to be either 1 or 2? How about where foo is a long long and bar is 1 or 2? Warnings for multiplying or adding bar to any signed constant, since the result of overflow is undefined? The compiler usually can't identify the logical constraints, so I'd expect any such warnings to be highly prone to false positives. Doesn't mean it's a bad idea, I'm just speculating why it's hard to define what it should be, and low priority for compiler writers anyway.

Comment: If the compiler warned on implicit widening casts (i.e. `(int)(1<<bar)` to `(long long)(1<<bar)` that would take care of OP's situation, but I don't see any options like that.  Not to mention that, like onebyone says, it would generate a lot of false positives...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what criteria you are thinking of to flag
this construction as suspicious. There is clearly
something wrong if the value of bar is as large as than
the size (in bits) of an int, but usually the compiler
wouldn't know that.
From the point of view of a heuristic, bug-finding tool,
having good patterns to separate likely bugs from
normal constructions is key to avoiding too many false
positives (which make users hate the tool and refuse to
use it).

The Open Source tool in my URL flags logical shifts by a number larger
than the size of the type, but it is primarily a verification
tool for critical embedded software and expect a lot of work
to appropriate it if you intend to use it on the Linux kernel
with its linked structures and other difficulties.

Comment: I'll have a look at your website. I realize that by suggesting bar at 64, I misled. I changed it to 16. Even then there's a problem, that lint catches but I'm looking for gcc to catch. Problem isn't the too-large-shift, per se. It's the complex expression with, unintended, multiple types in it.